# Items of ItemsPresenter in Custom-Control not shown correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls, scrollviewer

I've written a custom control that should display items in a list and provide additional commands related to scrolling events, like load more. So I decided to create a `ScrollViewer` and add the `ItemsPresenter` inside `generic.xaml`.

Basically this works fine when I use `ItemsControl` as base class. But now I need the possibility to click on a single item. The solution is to use the `ListView` class as base class.

Here comes the problem. As soon as I use a `GridView` or `ListView` as base class the content of the list is only shown as far as it is shown at inital offset of the list. other/new items that you can only see by scrolling down aren't shown.

[image]

I thought that the list maybe dont resize, but adding a footer and a border around the list shows the the list resizes correctly.

The collection I use is a `ObservableCollection` and works with the `ItemsControl` base class.

I think the problem is a setting or something on xaml side. But I dont know where and i have no ideas what to search next. everytime I search, all results are marked as clicked =(

Here is my xaml code of the `generic.xaml`:

```
<Style TargetType="lists:ListViewWithCommands">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>                
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="lists:ListViewWithCommands">
                <Border
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="Red"
                    BorderThickness="1">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ItemScrollViewer">
                        <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="2">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <ItemsPresenter />
                                <ContentPresenter Visibility="{TemplateBinding LoadingTemplateVisibility}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding LoadingTemplate}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Here is a part of my control itselve:

```
[TemplatePart(Name="ItemScrollViewer", Type=typeof(ScrollViewer))]
  public sealed class ListViewWithCommands : ListView
  {
      private ScrollViewer _itemScrollViewer;

      public ListViewWithCommands()
      {
          this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(ListViewWithCommands);
      }

      protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
      {
          base.OnApplyTemplate();
          this._itemScrollViewer = GetTemplateChild("ItemScrollViewer") as ScrollViewer;
          if (this._itemScrollViewer != null)
          {
              Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("ItemScrollViewer found! Attatching Event Handler!"), this.GetType().Name);
              this._itemScrollViewer.ViewChanged += _itemScrollViewer_ViewChanged;
          }
          else
          {
              throw new NullReferenceException("ItemScrollViewer not found!");
          }
      }
....
```

I hope you have any suggestions.

robert

Comment: This looks like wpf to me, maybe add a tag identifing that it´s wpf related.

Comment: yes, had some more tags in the list but its limited to 5. <.<

Comment: removed listview and added wpf as tag.